# Python : need performance to retrieve a string in a big list

Tags: python, performance, pattern-matching

email_process_list is a list whose elements are emails.
Each email is represented by a list of words.
I got a big list named words_to_delete that contains 36,000 words.
For each email, I want to delete words that are included in the words_to_delete.
Like as follow :

```
new=list()
for email in email_process_list:
    email_clean=[word for word in email if word not in words_to_delete]
    new.append(email_clean)
```

The problem : it takes so much time. I have 16Go Ram and it has run for hours. Thanks

Comment: Seems like an ideal case for a `set`.

Comment: Actually I think you should use regex. Create a pattern from all the words you don't want and use regex replace.

Comment: @ sudomakeinstall2 When you say a pattern does it refer to re.compile that I see sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List lookup is slow (linear time), set lookup is fast (constant time). Convert `words_to_delete` into a set before you start your loop.

If you run into problems with your memory, you can also shrink the original list as you process it. That way, you don't have to keep two versions of the same email (original and cleaned) in memory.

```
new=list()
words_to_delete = set(words_to_delete)
email_process_list = email_process_list[::-1]
while len(email_process_list) > 0:
    email = email_process_list.pop()
    email_clean=[word for word in email if word not in words_to_delete]
    new.append(email_clean)
```

I invert `email_process_list` to allow us to pop the first (now last) object, which is cheaper than calling `email_process_list.pop(0)`. If you don't care about the order of the emails in `new`, you can remove the third line.

Comment: No problem. If you think this answered your question sufficiently, feel free to mark it as solved